# How can I concatenate two arrays in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, arrays, concatenation

How do I concatenate two arrays to get a single array containing the elements of both original arrays?

Comment: Yeah... Since both answers appear to be responding to the "concatenation" interpretation, and the OP hasn't returned to clarify, I've edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 30):

Arrays in C simply are a contiguous area of memory, with a pointer to their start*. So merging them involves:

1. Find the length of the arrays A and B, (you will probably need to know the number of elements and the `sizeof` each element)
2. Allocating (`malloc`) a new array C that is the size of A + B.
3. Copy (`memcpy`) the memory from A to C,
4. Copy the memory from B to C + the length of A (see 1).
5. You might want also to de-allocate (`free`) the memory of A and B.

Note that this is an expensive operation, but this is the basic theory. If you are using a library that provides some abstraction, you might be better off. If A and B are more complicated then a simple array (e.g. sorted arrays), you will need to do smarter copying then steps 3 and 4 (see: [how do i merge two arrays having different values into one array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700182/how-do-i-merge-two-arrays-having-different-values-into-one-array)).

---

- Although for the purpose of this question, the pointer explanation will suffice,  strictly speaking (and for pacifying the commenter below): C *has* the concept of an array, that can be used without the syntax of pointers. Implementation wise, however, a C array and a contiguous area of memory, with a pointer are close enough they can be, and often are, used interchangeably.

Comment: Where did "...with a pointer to their start..." come from? When I declare `int a[10]` I get a contiguous area of memory with 10 `int` in it and no pointers whatsoever.

Comment: @AndreyT: `a` is your pointer. You appear to be aware of this in your comment on the other answer...

Comment: @Shog9: `a` is not a pointer. `a` is an array. When the array type decays to pointer type, the resultant pointer is just an intermediate temporary value, which has nothing to do with `a`. Wnat the post above states is incorrect, unless it talks specifically about `malloc`ed arrays.

Comment: A bit pedantic, eh? For the purpose of the algorithm described, it makes no difference (apart from the necessity of skipping step #5 in the case of stack-based arrays).

Comment: Stating that array is not a pointer is *not even remotely* pedantic. This is a rather popular and annoying misconception, so having it promoted here is definitely not a good idea.

Comment: @Shog9: int a[10] a in the symbol table has the memory address of the first element of a. this memory address call it whatever you want, is a memory address and not a C pointer. char *p, p in a symbol table has the address of a location to store p's value, and that value in a pointer to another value of type char. There is an extra dereference when using pointers and accessing them compared to arrays.