# Merging of two arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

If i have two arrays ,

```
A= [2,3,4] and B=[8,9,10].
```

How can i merge this two arrays.

```
Solution C=[2,3,4,8,9,10]
```

Please guide.

Comment: Sorted (as per your example) or unsorted? have you made any attempt?

Comment: Refer this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700182/how-do-i-merge-two-arrays-having-different-values-into-one-array

Answer (score 3):

1. Allocate space for array big enough for both A & B
2. Copy all elements from A
3. Copy all elements from B

If you mean merge and preserve some sort of order, then iterate over A & B simultaneously copying the next relevant(depending on your ordering criteria) value in to the next slot in the new array.