# How to append two arrays in C language?

Tags: c, arrays

How can I include the elements of array X and Y in to array `total` in C language ?
can you please show with an example.

```
X = (float*) malloc(4);
Y = (float*) malloc(4);
total = (float*) malloc(8);

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    h_x[i] = 1;
    h_y[i] = 2;
}

//How can I make 'total' have both the arrays x and y
//for example I would like the following to print out 
// 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2

for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    printf("%.1f, ", total[i]);
```

Comment: What's the problem? What have you tried? As I see, you know how to iterate through arrays..

Comment: Your first problem is that you allocate four and eight _bytes_ for `X`/`Y` and `total` respectively.

Comment: concatenation of two arrays in C has already been answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696074/how-can-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-c

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Your existing code is allocating the wrong amount of memory because it doesn't take `sizeof(float)` into account at all.

Other than that, you can append one array to the other with [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/):

```
float x[4] = { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
float y[4] = { 2, 2, 2, 2 };

float* total = malloc(8 * sizeof(float)); // array to hold the result

memcpy(total,     x, 4 * sizeof(float)); // copy 4 floats from x to total[0]...total[3]
memcpy(total + 4, y, 4 * sizeof(float)); // copy 4 floats from y to total[4]...total[7]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing me with an example. It was very helpful

Comment: [You should not cast the return of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: ...and it's better not to mention the type in sizeof: `float* total = malloc(8 * sizeof(*total));`

Comment: After the last memcpy is `total` seen as a bigger array or a `2x4` matrix?

Comment: @elmazzun not sure what you mean by "bigger array"? Anyway, `total` is not an array because it wasn't created with array syntax. The difference might seem small but it definitely exists.

Comment: Shouldn't you take into account the `sizeof(float)` when doing `total + 4`?

Comment: The memcpy URL link above returns a 404. Here's the updated link for [memcpy](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/)

Answer (score 3):

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    total[i]  =h_x[i] = 1;
    total[i+4]=h_y[i] = 2;
}
```

Comment: Only works for the specific example in the question, but not in the general case.

Comment: @stakx : I do not think most benefits can make a generic function also, I think the question in this case that the function is required there is no generic.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - definitely the two input arrays having the same number of elements is too special. Yet your solution specifically takes advantage of that.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd add this because I've found it necessary in the past to append values to a C array (like `NSMutableArray` in Objective-C). This code manages a C `float` array and appends values to it:

```
static float *arr;
static int length;

void appendFloat(float);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    float val = 0.1f;
    appendFloat(val);

    return 0;
}

void appendFloat(float val) {
    /*
     * How to manage a mutable C float array
     */
    // Create temp array
    float *temp = malloc(sizeof(float) * length + 1);
    if (length > 0 && arr != NULL) {
        // Copy value of arr into temp if arr has values
        memccpy(temp, arr, length, sizeof(float));
        // Free origional arr
        free(arr);
    }
    // Length += 1
    length++;
    // Append the value
    temp[length] = val;
    // Set value of temp to arr
    arr = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this is simple.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j,k,n,m,total,a[30],b[30],c[60];
    //getting array a
    printf("enter size of array A:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("enter %d elements \n",n);
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
    {scanf("%d",&a[i]);}

    //getting aaray b
    printf("enter size of array b:");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("enter %d elements \n",m);
    for(j=0;j<m;++j)
    {scanf("%d",&b[j]);}

    total=m+n;
    i=0,j=0;

    //concating starts    
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
       c[i]=a[i];
    }
    for(j=0;j<m;++j,++n)
    {
       c[n]=b[j];
    }

    printf("printing c\n");
    for(k=0;k<total;++k)
    {printf("%d\n",c[k]);}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution to concatenate two or more **statically-allocated** arrays. Statically-allocated arrays are array whose length is defined at compile time. The `sizeof` operator returns the size (in bytes) of these arrays:

```c
char Static[16];               // A statically allocated array
int n = sizeof(Static_array);  // n1 == 16
```

We can use the operator `sizeof` to build a set of macros that will **concatenate** two or more arrays, and possibly returns the total array length.

Our macros:

```c
#include <string.h>

#define cat(z, a)          *((uint8_t *)memcpy(&(z), &(a), sizeof(a)) + sizeof(a))
#define cat1(z, a)         cat((z),(a))
#define cat2(z, a, b)      cat1(cat((z),(a)),b)
#define cat3(z, a, b...)   cat2(cat((z),(a)),b)
#define cat4(z, a, b...)   cat3(cat((z),(a)),b)
#define cat5(z, a, b...)   cat4(cat((z),(a)),b)
// ... add more as necessary
#define catn(n, z, a ...)  (&cat ## n((z), a) - (uint8_t *)&(z)) // Returns total length
```

An example of use:

```c
char      One[1]   = { 0x11 };
char      Two[2]   = { 0x22, 0x22 };
char      Three[3] = { 0x33, 0x33, 0x33 };
char      Four[4]  = { 0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44 };
char      All[10];
unsigned  nAll = catn(4, All, One, Two, Three, Four);
```

However, thanks to the way we defined our macros, we can concatenate **any type of objects** as long as `sizeof` returns their size. For instance:

```c
char      One      = 0x11;                                // A byte
char      Two[2]   = { 0x22, 0x22 };                      // An array of two byte
char      Three[]  = "33";                                // A string ! 3rd byte = '\x00'
struct {
    char  a[2];
    short  b;
}         Four     = { .a = { 0x44, 0x44}, .b = 0x4444 }; // A structure
void *    Eight    = &One;                                // A 64-bit pointer
char      All[18];
unsigned  nAll     = catn(5, All, One, Two, Three, Four, Eight);
```

Using constant literals, one can also these macros to concatenate constants, results from functions, or even constant arrays:

```c
// Here we concatenate a constant, a function result, and a constant array
cat2(All,(char){0x11},(unsigned){some_fct()},((uint8_t[4]){1,2,3,4}));
```

Answer (score 0):

i like the answer from jon. In my case i had to use a static solution.
So if you are forced to not use dynamic memory allocation:

```
int arr1[5] = {11,2,33,45,5};
int arr2[3] = {16,73,80};
int final_arr[8];

memcpy(final_arr, arr1, 5 * sizeof(int));
memcpy(&final_arr[5], arr2, 3 * sizeof(int));

for(int i=0; i<(sizeof(final_arr)/sizeof(final_arr[0]));i++){
    printf("final_arr: %i\n", final_arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use simple logic like this?

[image]

```
#include<stdio.h>  
  
#define N 5  
#define M (N * 2)  
  
int main()  
{  
    int a[N], b[N], c[M], i, index = 0;  
  
    printf("Enter %d integer numbers, for first array\n", N);  
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)  
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);  
  
    printf("Enter %d integer numbers, for second array\n", N);  
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)  
            scanf("%d", &b[i]);  
  
    printf("\nMerging a[%d] and b[%d] to form c[%d] ..\n", N, N, M);  
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)  
        c[index++] = a[i];  
  
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)  
        c[index++] = b[i];  
  
    printf("\nElements of c[%d] is ..\n", M);  
    for(i = 0; i < M; i++)  
        printf("%d\n", c[i]);  
  
    return 0;  
}
```

Resultant array size must be equal to the size of array a and b.

*Source:* [C Program To Concatenate Two Arrays](https://technotip.com/8880/c-program-to-concatenate-two-arrays/)